# Redirect_to :back with :alert not working as expected in specific situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page with a `form_tag` to determine parameters for the generation of a plain text file:

```
<%= form_tag(remessa_individual_boletos_path, :method => "get",  :target => "_blank", :class => "form_change_action", :id => "form-remessa") do %>
...
```

Once the form is submitted, some things need to be checked and if something goes wrong, I have to inform the user. The way this is done in the rest of the system is by redirecting back and displaying a message in an alert:

```
redirect_to :back, alert: "É necessário definir o limite de remessas por dia da conta bancária."
```

The line of code where the file is actually generated and downloaded is a `send_data`:

```
send_data @geraboleto.geraremessaboletoindividual(params[:banco_id], current_user.id), :content_type => 'text/plain', :filename => @geraboleto.filename
```

However, when there is in fact an error, instead of simply refreshing the page and displaying the alert, the `:target => "_blank"` ends up opening a new tab with the same URL as the page where the form is, so the user ends up with two tabs in the same address, but the alert appears on the original tab, which is not visible at this point because the new tab is on the screen, which means that the user may not see the alert and not understand why their file was not generated.

When I remove `:target => "_blank"` and submit the form, in the case of error the expected behaviour happens: The page refreshes and the alert is shown. However when no errors happen, the file is generated but not downloaded (no prompt to save or open the file either), so I assume I need this bit of code...

To sum it up: I need to be able to download a file via `send_data`, for which I think I need `:target => "_blank"`, but I also need to be able to show an alert to the user when an error occurs, in which case `:target => "_blank"` seems to be a problem. How can I have these two situations work?

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the `"_blank"` target to download the file, just let the `send_data` in the controller action.

```
# your/view.html.erb

<%= form_tag(remessa_individual_boletos_path, :method => "get", ...) do %>
# ...

# YourController

def action
  if valid?
    send_data ...
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: 'Alert message'
  end
end
```